# Passing data frame column as an argument in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns:

```
> names(mh)
 [1] "subj" "cond" "tpxx_150_brod_atl_comp_features.nii"
 [4] "tpxx_150_brod_atl_ant_features.nii" "tpxx_150_l_atl_features.nii" "tpxx_150_b38_features.nii"              
 [7] "tpxx_150_frontal_features.nii" "tpxx_150_fronto_temporal_features.nii" "tpxx_150_inf_frontal_gyrus_features.nii" 
 [10] "tpxx_150_inf_temporal_gyrus_features.nii" "tpxx_150_temporal_features.nii"
```

I need to produce graphs for a bunch of these columns.  Here is one such:

```
qplot(tpxx_150_temporal_features.nii, main="tpxx_150_temporal_features.nii", facets=cond ~ ., geom="histogram", binwidth=.01, xlim=c(.4,.9), ylab="pct", fill=subj, data=mh)
```

I need to do this over and over, so I'd like to just automate it:

```
for (colName in names(mh)[3:11]) { 
     print(qplot(colName, main=colName, facets=cond ~ ., geom="histogram", binwidth=.01, xlim=c(.4,.9), ylab="pct", fill=subj, data=mh)) 
}
```

except that doesn't work.  I'm making *colName* a string, and qplot doesn't want a string; rather (in the vernacular of general programming languages) it seems to want some kind of reference to a variable in the data frame.  But I don't know how to convert one to the other, and I don't know the right R terminology to use to look up the answer.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `mh` be your data.frame.

```
    for (colName in names(mh)[3:11]) { 
         print(qplot(mh[ , colName], main=colName, facets=cond ~ ., geom="histogram", 
         binwidth=.01, xlim=c(.4,.9), ylab="pct", fill=subj, data=mh)) 
    }
```

Now you're accessing that actual column.